# Resulting clime of fictional world geography

Tags: internal-consistency, climate, geography, map-making

[image: My World Map]

I'm writing a fantasy story, and I've recently come up with a world map. This probably isn't the final version (I'll probably add some more islands), but this gives me a general idea of where everything is.

---

My question is:

## What would the climate of this world be?

Based on plate tectonics and ocean currents and assuming that the ocean currents work the same as on Earth (two main currents both above and below the equator. The equator in this map is just above the island east of the southwest continent).

---

(In case you notice something I might have missed or gotten wrong, please feel free to shout out).

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. It's hard to call a map a collection of blue and white spots. I miss latitude/longitude grids and elevation, just to tell a few. Then, since we prefer answering well defined problem, it would be better if your question complied to our standards. Asking for critiques has the potential of generating an endless list. You can find more in the [help] and taking the [tour]

Comment: Since it's one of the subjects of the week, what projection are you using (what is distorted and what is preserved)?

Comment: Hi Richard, and welcome to Worldbuilding! “Climate” is usually used to refer to a region *within* a planet, so talking about the planet’s climate as a whole is rather broad. The rainforests of the Amazon, after all, have a very different climate from the deserts of the Sahara or the Antarctic. We’ll also need to know a bit more about your planet’s position relative to its star to figure out average temps and precipitation maps. If this is meant to be an Earth-like world in all respects except the continent distribution, that would be great info to [edit] into your question.

Comment: *what would the climate of this world be* This is really too broad.  Deducing a planet's climate and weather patterns is incredibly complex and small differences in e.g. atmospheric gases can have huge differences in the resulting weather patterns (as we should now all understand due to global climate change we have induced on Earth).

Comment: @StephenG indeed. You could have significant differences in climate from just terrain - mountains or forests might create a different weather pattern for some areas. Also true - just [random stuff in the atmosphere](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/139601/could-comets-or-meteors-be-used-to-combat-global-warming/139670) could have a *huge* impact.

Comment: Yeah sorry, your edit didn't make this less broad.  You would need to define ocean currents, wind, mountains, everything.  A better question would be asking if your planned climate is realistic based on the geography of a very small area.  If you want to make a sort of "this is the polar region, this is the desert region" sort of sweeping generalizations, then you should just invent story rules as to why.  If you ask how to make a certain area a desert, we can help with that.

Comment: Sorry for how vague the map is. Hearing people's suggestions have made me realize the various things I need to consider. It'll be a while before I'm able to update the map, so this thread can be closed/deleted.

Comment: Apart from temperature zones don't forget that even the whole climate on a planet can change, from the ice age to warmer times when there were hippos swimming in the Thames... And as you are writing a fantasy story, are there fantastic elements connected to the climate? The best example for that would be G. R. R. Martin's world of ice and fire (Game of Thrones) with winters and summers that last for decades and occur irregularly.

Comment: Like a zone where some elves or shamans or the enchanted temple ruins of some long gone civilization preserves warm climate in the middle of the ice desert (or the opposite).